# How to hide TOC from sidebar in sphinx.ext.autosummary?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, toctree

I need Sphinx autosummary extension to generate stub using `:toctree: generated/` but I also want to prevent TOC entries from appearing in the HTML sidebar. Consider following docstring:

```
MySubPackage (mypackage.mysubpackage)
=====================================

Some Title
----------

.. currentmodule:: mypackage.mysubpackage

Some description


.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 1

   mypackage.mysubpackage.mysubsubpackage1
   mypackage.mysubpackage.mysubsubpackage2

Sub-Packages
------------

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated/

   mysubsubpackage1
   mysubsubpackage2
```

Each `subsubpackage` contain further private `subsubsubpackages` with classes and methods that are exposed in the docstring of `subsubpackage`'s `__init__.py` file. The `autosummary` successfully generates stub files for all classes and functions in these `subsubpackages` but do not generate stub .rst files for intermediate packages. In the end, I am left with missing stub files without which neither TOC entries are present nor module path for classes and methods of subsubsubpackages. Using Sphinx's `.. toctree::` directive solve the half of the problem by generating intermediate stub files. However, I end up with duplicated entries in the sidebar TOC. All I need is to either make autosummary to generate intermediate stub files or use some kind of option for autosummary like `:hiddentoc:` so that it keeps the generating stub files but not adding to entries to the TOC. I am relatively new to Sphinx and I try to automate the documentation generation process using only docstrings.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `:hidden:` hides links from the document or sidebar. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! For anyone who had similar issues, please read on.

The problem was caused due to repeated usage of `:toctree: generated/` option in `__init__.py` files of sub-packages. It was causing autosummary extension to create nested `/generated/generated/..` directories so it was not able to locate the *.stub files. After removing the output directory path and leaving it as simply `:toctree:`, the problem was solved and there was no need to use additional `.. toctree::` along with `.. autosummary::` directive.